# Paypal express checkout Error 10400. Order Total Is missing Php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

hello friends i am getting legedanry paypal 10400 Error : Order total is missing. Please review and help me for this. im still getting the same error. Here is what i send:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../config.php");
include_once("paypal.class.php");

$paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

if($_POST) //Post Data received from product list page.
{
    //Other important variables like tax, shipping cost
    $TotalTaxAmount     = 0.00;  //Sum of tax for all items in this order. 
    $HandalingCost      = 0.00;  //Handling cost for this order.
    $InsuranceCost      = 0.00;  //shipping insurance cost for this order.
    $ShippinDiscount    = 0.00; //Shipping discount for this order. Specify this as negative number.
    $ShippinCost        = 0.00; //Although you may change the value later, try to pass in a shipping amount that is reasonably accurate.

    //we need 4 variables from product page Item Name, Item Price, Item Number and Item Quantity.
    //Please Note : People can manipulate hidden field amounts in form,
    //In practical world you must fetch actual price from database using item id. 
    //eg : $ItemPrice = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_price FROM products WHERE id = Product_Number");
    $paypal_data ='';
    $ItemTotalPrice = 0;

    foreach($_POST['item_code'] as $key=>$itm_name)
    {
        $product_code   = filter_var($_POST['item_code'][$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 



        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_name'][$key]);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_code'][$key]);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_price'][$key]);       
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

        // item price X quantity
        $subtotal = ($_POST['item_price'][$key]*$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

        //total price
        $ItemTotalPrice = $ItemTotalPrice + $subtotal;

        //create items for session
        $paypal_product['items'][] = array('itm_name'=>$_POST['item_name'][$key],
                                            'itm_price'=>$_POST['item_price'][$key],
                                            'itm_code'=>$_POST['item_code'][$key], 
                                            'itm_qty'=>$_POST['item_qty'][$key]
                                            );
    }

    //Grand total including all tax, insurance, shipping cost and discount
    $GrandTotal = ($ItemTotalPrice + $TotalTaxAmount + $HandalingCost + $InsuranceCost + $ShippinCost + $ShippinDiscount);


    $paypal_product['assets'] = array('tax_total'=>$TotalTaxAmount, 
                                'handaling_cost'=>$HandalingCost, 
                                'insurance_cost'=>$InsuranceCost,
                                'shippin_discount'=>$ShippinDiscount,
                                'shippin_cost'=>$ShippinCost,
                                'grand_total'=>$GrandTotal);

    //create session array for later use
    $_SESSION["paypal_products"] = $paypal_product;

    //Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal
    $padata =   '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout'.

                '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
                '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
                $paypal_data.               
                '&NOSHIPPING=0'. //set 1 to hide buyer's shipping address, in-case products that does not require shipping
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($TotalTaxAmount).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($ShippinCost).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($HandalingCost).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($ShippinDiscount).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($InsuranceCost).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($GrandTotal).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
                '&LOCALECODE=GB'. //PayPal pages to match the language on your website.
                '&LOGOIMG=http://plant-a-tree.co/skin/frontend/default/sk24/images/logo_es.jpg'. //site logo
                '&CARTBORDERCOLOR=FFFFFF'. //border color of cart
                '&ALLOWNOTE=1';

        //We need to execute the "SetExpressCheckOut" method to obtain paypal token
        $paypal= new MyPayPal();
        $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

        //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
        if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
        {
                //Redirect user to PayPal store with Token received.
                $paypalurl ='https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';
                header('Location: '.$paypalurl);
        }
        else
        {
            //Show error message
            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

}

//Paypal redirects back to this page using ReturnURL, We should receive TOKEN and Payer ID
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["PayerID"]))
{
    //we will be using these two variables to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"
    //Note: we haven't received any payment yet.

    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $payer_id = $_GET["PayerID"];

    //get session variables
    $paypal_product = $_SESSION["paypal_products"];
    $paypal_data = '';
    $ItemTotalPrice = 0;
    foreach($paypal_product['items'] as $key=>$p_item)
    {       
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($p_item['itm_qty']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_price']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_name']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_code']);

        // item price X quantity
        $subtotal = ($p_item['itm_price']*$p_item['itm_qty']);

        //total price
        $ItemTotalPrice = ($ItemTotalPrice + $subtotal);
    }

    $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
                '&PAYERID='.urlencode($payer_id).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
                $paypal_data.
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['tax_total']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['shippin_cost']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['handaling_cost']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['shippin_discount']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['insurance_cost']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['grand_total']).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode);

    //We need to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" at this point to Receive payment from user.
    $paypal= new MyPayPal();
    $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

    //Check if everything went ok..
    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
    {

            echo '<h2>Success</h2>';
            echo 'Your Transaction ID : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID"]);

                /*
                //Sometimes Payment are kept pending even when transaction is complete. 
                //hence we need to notify user about it and ask him manually approve the transiction
                */

                if('Completed' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
                {
                    echo '<div style="color:green">Payment Received! Your product will be sent to you very soon!</div>';
                }
                elseif('Pending' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
                {
                    echo '<div style="color:red">Transaction Complete, but payment is still pending! '.
                    'You need to manually authorize this payment in your <a target="_new" href="http://www.paypal.com">Paypal Account</a></div>';
                }

                // we can retrive transection details using either GetTransactionDetails or GetExpressCheckoutDetails
                // GetTransactionDetails requires a Transaction ID, and GetExpressCheckoutDetails requires Token returned by SetExpressCheckOut
                $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token);
                $paypal= new MyPayPal();
                $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

                if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
                {

                    echo '<br /><b>Stuff to store in database :</b><br />';

                    echo '<pre>';
                    /*
                    #### SAVE BUYER INFORMATION IN DATABASE ###
                    //see (http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage) for mysqli usage
                    //use urldecode() to decode url encoded strings.

                    $buyerName = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["FIRSTNAME"]).' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["LASTNAME"]);
                    $buyerEmail = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["EMAIL"]);

                    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
                    $mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

                    //Output any connection error
                    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                    }       

                    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
                    (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
                    VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID','$ItemName',$ItemNumber, $ItemTotalPrice,$ItemQTY)");

                    if($insert_row){
                        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }

                    */

                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                    echo '</pre>';
                } else  {
                    echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                    echo '</pre>';

                }

    }else{
            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
            echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

Getting error 10400. Someone please look at this code and please tell me where i am wrong and why i am getting this legendary error.

```
Error : Order total is missing.
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d03%2d12T20%3a11%3a31Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => c8561bcba6df4
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 15735246
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10400
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Order%20total%20is%20missing%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```